# Calculating missing values by calculating average based on few conditions

Tags: sas

I have a data set with lots of flight information, in the below format.

```
carrier flight origin   dest air_time
9E  4194    EWR ATL     105
9E  4362    EWR ATL     .
9E  4362    EWR ATL     117
9E  3633    EWR ATL     113
```

The second record, does not have the air_time data available. The business requirement is that in such cases;

1. I should find the average air_time for the air craft carrier code,
   use the same departure, and destination airports
2. Populate this average air_time as the air_time for row #2, which has the missing data.

I am unable to code this in SAS. The code should do this for every time a missing value is found in air_time. Request experts to help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The term for this is *missing data imputation*,  and specifically, imputation with the mean.  This is a pretty common task, and one well covered by a brief search on the internet.  Please do so, and then make an effort to solve this problem; if you have questions about that approach, come back and ask them.

Comment: Also - please take a look at [ask].  This site isn't intended for "please write code for me to do this task" questions: if your question consists of "here is my business requirement", it's not a question, it's an unpaid consulting job.  We're here and happy to help with understanding how things work and how to fix issues, but we're not here to do your job *for* you.

Comment: [proc mi](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mi_sect001.htm) is the generalised way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, and sorry for troubling all of you.Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me perfectly.
Step #1, sorted the variables using which I planned to find the average values.

```
proc sort data=cs1.flights_cln out=cs1.flights_srt;
    by carrier origin dest;
run;
```

Step #2, used the standar procedure. After I ran this code, the missing values in the data set, got replaced with the average values.

```
proc standard data=cs1.flights_srt out=cs1.flights_stn replace;
    by carrier origin dest;
run;
```